# How to do a comparison operator on dynamic and string

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have two http request that are binded to the following models:

```
    public class ShopifyAPI
{
    public class ShopifyAPIAuth
    {
        [Required]
        public required string AccessToken { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public required string Key { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public required string Secret { get; set; }
    }


    public class ShopifyOrderResponse
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("orders")]
        public required List<ShopifyOrder>? Orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShopifyOrder
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("order_number")]
        public required long OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("financial_status")]
        public required string PaymentStatus { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("shipping_address")]
        public required Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("billing_address")]
        public required Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("line_items")]
        public required List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("first_name")]
        public required string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("last_name")]
        public required string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("address1")]
        public required string Address1 { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("address2")]
        public string? Address2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("city")]
        public required string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("province")]
        public required string State { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("zip")]
        public required string Zipcode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        public required string Country { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("phone")]
        public string? Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("product_id")]
        public long? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("title")]
        public string? ProductName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("variant_id")]
        public long? VariationId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("variant_title")]
        public string? VariationName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("quantity")]
        public long? Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class WoocommerceAPI
{
    public class WoocommerceAPIAuth
    {
        [Required]
        public required string Key { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public required string Secret { get; set; }
    }

    public class WoocommerceOrder
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("status")]
        public required string Status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("shipping")]
        public required Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("billing")]
        public required Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("line_items")]
        public required List<Product> Products { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("meta_data")]
        public required List<MetaData> MetaDatas { get; set; }

    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("first_name")]
        public required string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("last_name")]
        public required string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("address_1")]
        public required string Address1 { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("address_2")]
        public string? Address2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("city")]
        public required string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("state")]
        public required string State { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("postcode")]
        public required string Zipcode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        public required string Country { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("phone")]
        public string? Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("product_id")]
        public long? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string? ProductName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("variation_id")]
        public long? VariationId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("quantity")]
        public long? Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetaData
    {
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public required dynamic Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("key")]
        public required dynamic Key { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("value")]
        public required dynamic Value { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I use these models in the following controller:

```
    [HttpPost(Name = "PostDataExport")]
    [EnableRateLimiting("api")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        Task<List<ShopifyOrder>> importShopifyOrders = _shopifyService.GetOrders("https://dirtdudesutv.myshopify.com", _shopifyAPIAuth.AccessToken);
        Task<List<WoocommerceOrder>> importWoocommerceOrders = _woocommerceService.GetOrders("https://www.aaaprintco.com", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{_woocommerceAPIAuth.Key}:{_woocommerceAPIAuth.Secret}")));

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task> { importShopifyOrders, importWoocommerceOrders };
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        foreach (var order in importShopifyOrders.Result)
        {
            bool alreadyImportedOrder = importWoocommerceOrders.Result.Any(o => o.MetaDatas.Any(m =>(m.Key == "_shopify_order_id" && m.Value.ToString() == order.Id.ToString())));

            if(alreadyImportedOrder)
            {
                importShopifyOrders.Result.Remove(order);
            }
        }

        return Ok(importWoocommerceOrders.Result);
    }
}
```

The purpose of this controller is I pull all shopify orders and all woocommerce orders. I then need to find which shopify orders are already in woocommerce orders and if the order exists as shown in the foreach loop then it will delete it from the list. The issue is to check if the order exists in woocommerce there is a meta data field (as shown in the model) that has different meta data items. One of them is _shopify_order_id. So I nested some any LINQ statements to try and loop through and see if it exists. The issue I think is i use dynamic for the types since the meta data values are different types it seems. So when I run this I get an error at the meta data comparison:

```
    Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' and 'string'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Object, String)
```

I am thinking there is an issue comparing string to dynamic?

Comment: Why is `Key` `dynamic`? Do you get values other than strings back? What do you expect the comparison result to be in that case?

Comment: To help understand, `dynamic` is not a "type" - it basically tells the compiler "I do not know what the type is, so defer any bindings until runtime. If the value of `Key` was a string at runtime, the comparison would work fine.

Comment: Found the issue. I guess m.Key needs to be m.Key.ToString() . I made it dynamic because it would trip an error that it couldnt convert string to int at times. So I am guessing sometimes the data isnt always a string. So isnt dynamic the best to do or can I force everyything to a string when binding?

Comment: If `Key` can be either a string or an int, then `dynamic` is fine. I would recommend adding a type check to your comparison though (`m.Key is string && m.Key == "_shopify_order_id"`)

Comment: I would not force to a string at binding if you expect the key values of `123` and `"123"` to be different. You're not doing that in this case, but I don;t know what other values of `Key` could be and if those _should_ be treated differently.

Comment: So adding ToString() will that error out for some reason if not a string since its suppose to convert? If you could add type cast check to reduce any potential errors and I will accept answer

Comment: It "works" in that you don't get a cast error but comparing strings to things that are not strings can be tricky. e.g. if Tag was 123 but you said `Tag.ToString=="123"`, then both `123` and `"123"` would be true, which might be _correct_ but it's better to be explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ToString` on both sides to do a comparison can be tricky. It would be better to use `string.Equals` which requires that the other item be a string:

```
"_shopify_order_id".Equals(m.Key) && (m.Value.ToString() == order.Id.ToString())
```

I would also be caution about using `ToString` on the order ID comparison - if you had an order with an ID value "123" and a key with value `123`, the comparison would be true even if they were of different types.

So you *might* also want:

```
"_shopify_order_id".Equals(m.Key) && order.Id.Equals(m.Value)
```